# Search list and return the whole entry

Tags: file, list, search, groovy, split

I try to read a textfile and find a given parameter, if this is true, it should deliver me the whole list entry.

Thats the input in the file: 100 0100045391 0400053454 0502028765251 ABH ZL1 1560112 07.06.2010 100 0100045394 0400055024 0502028766382 ABH ZL1 1601944 21.06.2010

But at the moment I just can check if this parameter is in the list or not or the given parameter himself.

```
import groovy.util.CharsetToolkit;
//Pathname
def pathname = "C:/mySupport-eclipse/trackandtrace.txt"
//Error State
int errorCode = 0

def bsknr = "0100045553"
//Define new file
def file = new File(pathname)

if(!file.exists())
    {
        errorCode = 1   
    }
    else
    {
        //Read lines, seperated by tab
        file.splitEachLine ('\t') { 
            list -> list

            println list.findAll {it.contains(bsknr)}

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression, which would return the whole line that contains the parameter. Together with Groovy's built-in [File.filterLine(Closure)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#filterLine%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method, you get something like that:

```
def lines = file.filterLine { line -> line ==~ /.*\t${bsknr}\t.*/ }
```

If you want `lines` to be a string, you can do:

```
def linesAsString = lines.toString()
```

If you want them to be a list, you would do:

```
def linesAsList = lines.toString().tokenize("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean your input file is:

```
100 0100045391  0400053454  0502028765251   ABH ZL1 156011207.06.2010
100 0100045394  0400055024  0502028766382   ABH ZL1 160194421.06.2010
```

And assuming you mean *"How can I get a list of the lines containing this string"* (I have no idea what *'But at the moment I just can check if this parameter is in the list or not or the given parameter himself.'* means), then you can do this:

```
//Pathname
def pathname = "C:/mySupport-eclipse/trackandtrace.txt"
//Error State
int errorCode = 0

def bsknr = "0100045553"
def lines = []

//Define new file
def file = new File( pathname )

if(!file.exists()) {
  errorCode = 1   
}
else {
  //Read lines, seperated by tab
  file.eachLine { line ->
    if( line.split( /\t/ ).grep { bsknr } ) lines << line 
  }
}

println lines
```